# Copying ArrayList from another ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

I am reading a book about Java APIs and it shows 3 ways of creating ArrayLists:
[image]

Regarding **the last statement**, the book states: " *(...) tells Java that we
want to make a copy of another ArrayList. We copy both the size and contents of that
ArrayList. Granted, list2 is empty in this example so it isn’t particularly interesting.*"

My question is would the reference list3 point to the same ArrayList in memory created by list2 or would they each point to their own Arraylists (with list3's ArrayList being similar to list2's ArrayList, in size and contents)?

Comment: When creating an ArrayList using the constructor new ArrayList<>(anotherList), a new ArrayList (list3) is created with the same elements and size as the provided ArrayList (list2), but they are distinct objects in memory.

Comment: Probably you would have spent less time testing this in your IDE than posting this question.

Comment: yes, you can test it yourself: list3.add(23); System.out.println(list2.size());

Comment: `list3` will be a new instance of `ArrayList`, but with the same content as `list2` So  `list2 == list3` will result in false, while `list2.equals(list3)` results in true. BTW it is not recommended to use Raw Types as posted (typed code would be `ArrayList<String> list1 = new ArrayList<>();`

Comment: The `new` keyword always creates *new/separate* objects. After such object is created code of *constructor* is called usually to *set up* internal state of that new object. Information about how it should be set are usually passed as constructor arguments. Here reference to `list2` was passed, so now newly created list knows from which *other* list it should copy content/settings. BTW what you see here is called "copy constructor".

Comment: Yes Pshesmo, I overlooked the role of the new keyword, which is a constructor i.e. it creates a totally separate arraylist object in memory, referenced only by list3.  

user85421 that's a good way to test my case using reference comparison == and content comparison using .equals(). I haven't touched Java in long time but Its coming to memory again. Thank you for all the answers.

Comment: This book is teaching you to create raw types which went out of style when Java 5 was released on September 30, 2004. Garbage collect this book post haste.

Comment: LOL @DavidConrad yes I am aware as of Java 5 we use Generics to define the type of ArrayList. This is an old PDF I found online and it got me immersed back into the nuances of Java.

Comment: @codeinsteinn Oracle provides free-of-charge a good tutorial, [*The Java Tutorials*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/). Based on Java 8, but very little of it is outdated.

Answer (score 2):

The content of `list2` is copied to `list3`, in fact, `list2` doesn't have to be of type `ArrayList` it can be any implementation of `Collection`.

What it does not do, is copy the elements, only their references. This means that if you add an element to `list2` after constructing `list3` that element is not removed from `list3`, and if you add an element to `list3` it will not be added to `list2`.

However, since the content of the objects contained is not copied, just their references. If you have a mutable object in both lists, for example, because it was present in `list2`, since that element is in both lists, the element itself is seen as modified in both, no matter if you accessed it from `list2` or `list3`.

Comment: So if I understand, you are saying the ONLY aspect of commonality between both arraylists would be at creation, where list3 is creating its own arraylist by referencing list2's size and (null) contents? Then any changes to either would NOT be known/accessed/reflected in the other? Is that correct?

Comment: `list3` does not references `list2` size, it is initialized with the same sazie, just because it will contain the same amount of elements, you can see in the [reference implementation](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/19c9388c2001b7b3d21624e2dd4ab4fdd8821e2f/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/ArrayList.java#L181) that the constructor will ask the other collection "array" view, and get the size from there. It does not reference directly the `list2`'s size. And it will be empty because that array is empty as well, but there is no `null`content.

Answer (score 1):

> would the reference list3 point to the same ArrayList in memory created by list2 or would they each point to their own Arraylists (with list3's ArrayList being similar to list2's ArrayList, in size and contents)?

### tl;dr

When invoking the [`ArrayList(Collection<? extends E> c`)](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/ArrayList.html#%3Cinit%3E(java.util.Collection)) constructor, the object references of the original list are copied into the elements of the new list.

Your code example never assigned any references. So you end up with three separate `ArrayList` objects, all with the same [size](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/ArrayList.html#size()) of zero.

### Details

As mentioned in correct [Answer by Andrés Alcarraz](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77809383/642706), a collection of objects in Java is always a collection of [references](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_(computer_science)), each reference pointing to an object (or `null`, having no reference no anything).

Example:

```java
ArrayList< String > petSpecies = new ArrayList<>() ;
species.add( "dog" ) ;
species.add( "cat" ) ;
```

| petSpecies |
| --- |
| dog |
| cat |

We have three objects in memory at this point. There is an `ArrayList` object. And there is a string "dog" floating around in memory somewhere, plus a string object holding the text "cat" floating around.

The dog and cat strings are conceptually tethered to the `ArrayList` because the first slot in that list holds a *reference* to "dog" string object, and the second slot holds a reference to the "cat" string object.

Think of the reference as a rope, like a rope tying a boat to a dock. While standing on the dock, we can follow one end of the first rope to its other end, and voilà, the first boat. Likewise, we follow the rope tied at the second slot of the dock to reach the second boat.

```java
ArrayList< String > moreSpecies = new ArrayList<>( petSpecies ) ;
```

| moreSpecies |
| --- |
| dog |
| cat |

At this point we have a fourth object in memory. We have another, separate, `ArrayList` object. After instantiating that object, the constructor copied the references from the first list into the second list. So we have *not* duplicated the string objects. In memory we still have only two strings, one "dog" and one "cat".

The boat metaphor gets a bit clumsy here, but imagine a second dock (second list) in our marina (memory). The first slot at that other dock also has a rope tied to the first boat. And its second slot has a rope tied to the second boat. Just two boats, but more ropes.

```java
moreSpecies.add( "whale" ) ;
```

Result:

| moreSpecies |
| --- |
| dog |
| cat |
| whale |

At this point we have fifth object, another `String` object holding the text "whale". The third slot of the second list holds a reference to that "whale" string.

Back to our boats, that would be a total of three boats, and two docks. The first two boats are attached to two docks, while the third boat is attached only to one dock.

The lists are independent. Let's delete "cat" from the first list.

```
petSpecies.remove( 1 ) ;  // Annoying zero-based index counting. Second position is at index # 1.
```

Notice that the second list retains its own reference to "cat" string object.

| petSpecies |
| --- |
| dog |

| moreSpecies |
| --- |
| dog |
| cat |
| whale |

In our boat analogy, we dropped the rope connecting the first dock to the second boat.

No `String` was harmed in the call to `List#remove` — all we deleted was one of the two references pointing to "cat" string object.

In your code example, you end up with three docks, but no boats. You never made any boats (`String` objects), just docks (`ArrayList` objects).

In your code:

- The first `ArrayList` is backed by an array of some default size. None were used, so the ArrayList reports its size as zero.
- For the second `ArrayList`, you specified an initial capacity of ten, so it is backed by an array of ten. None were used, so the ArrayList reports its size as zero.
- When creating the third `ArrayList`, you passed an `ArrayList`. The passed list held nothing, so the new list also holds nothing. With no assignments held, the new third ArrayList reports its size as zero. Its capacity is unknown to us, as no behavior is specified by the `ArrayList` documentation.

---

We can demonstrate how your three resulting `ArrayList` objects are independent of one another.

```java
ArrayList < String > list1 = new ArrayList() ;
list1.add( "France" ) ;
list1.add( "Spain" ) ;

ArrayList < String > list2 = new ArrayList( 10 ) ;
list2.add( "Canada" ) ;

ArrayList < String > list3 = new ArrayList( list2 ) ;
list3.add( "Mexico" ) ;
```

When [run at Ideone.com](https://ideone.com/daGq6d):

```
list1.toString() ➡️ [France, Spain]
list2.toString() ➡️ [Canada]
list3.toString() ➡️ [Canada, Mexico]
```

---

By the way, when no more ropes are tied to a boat, that boat becomes a candidate for eventual [garbage collection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_(computer_science)). That is how allocated memory is freed in a [Java Virtual Machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_virtual_machine).

---

In full technical disclosure, `String` objects in Java are very special. A string literal in Java may be already existing in a pool before running our lines of code above, already instantiated when the app launches. But let's ignore that fact here.

Comment: Great answer. Please check my reply to Andrez answer above and let me know if you agree or not.

Comment: @codeinsteinn I added some example code with `List#add` calls. To demonstrate how your three lists are separate.